# How do I have my svg image wrap all the way around the edge of my oval?

Tags: shrinkwrap

I have imported my svg image, converted it to a mesh, then when i use shrinkwrap it goes up against the flatter length of the cylinder fine, but when i move it over the more curved parts of the shape it distorts or cuts off.

My aim is to have the pattern wrapped around the whole edge of the cylinder then give it a thickness so when i boolean it, it will create and engraving effect.

What am i doing wrong? and is there a better way for me to achieve this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: if you use Shrinkwrap the object should rotate around its target but I'm afraid it won't work fine, so you probably need to use another method like Array + Curve modifiers

Answer (score 0):

The *Shrinkwrap* modifier won't project your ornment object around the cylinder target, unless the ornment itself turns around the target. It will be hard to get something correct with a *Shrinkwrap*.

What you can do though is duplicate one edge of your cylinder, make it a new object, convert to curve:

[image]

Now select the ornment and give it an *Array* modifier and a *Curve* modifier (with the created curve as *Curve Object*), it will make the ornment rotate around the curve:

[image]

Comment: How can we copy an edge and make it independent from the object?

Comment: @Unapedra in Edit mode Alt right click to select the edge loop, Shift D to duplicate, P to separate selection as another object, then switch to Object mode, select the new object and right click > Convert To > Curve